# How to extend a cloned golang library using workspace approach

Tags: go

I'm writing a golang application and want to make use of an existing library.
But that lib lacks some features, so I decided to fork the repo and add my new features to it.

To be able to use the forked/extended lib in my application, I used the "workspace" feature of golang.

`go.work` in my application repo looks like

```golang
go 1.21.4

use (
    .
    ../go-git-cmd-wrapper // this is the local path to the forked/edited lib repo
)
```

This works fine, as long as I only extend existing packages within the forked lib.
I.e. as soon as I start creating a new package in the forked lib, I get build errors like the following:

I added a new package in the forked/cloned lib `go-git-cmd-wrapper/log/log.go` with this content

```golang
package log

.... // my new functionality
```

e.g. in my application I import the existing and new package of the lib

```golang
package main

import (
    ....
    // the following three work as expected, i.e. I can add new functionality
    // to those packages and use them in my application
    gwbranch "github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/branch"
    gwconfig "github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/config"
    gw "github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/git"
    // the following doesn't work, I get import error on build
    gwlog "github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/log"
    ....
)
```

```
 go: finding module for package github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/log
          go: changeme imports
                github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/log: module github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2@latest found (v2.6.0), but does not contain package github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2/log
          exit status 1
```

How can I fix such errors ? What am I doing wrong with respect to workspace and/or the forked lib ?

Comment: I already tried "go clean -modcache" in the application build, but build error still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do what you're trying to do using the workspace feature alone. This is because the go tools reading the module paths in your main import will call out to the remote repository, which is the original module. See: https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-find
You should instead use the `replace` feature of go modules, which is designed for this use case. Keep the fork in your go workspace, but add the following to your go.mod:

```
module your-module

go 1.21.4

require github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper v2.6.0

replace github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper v2.6.0 => ../go-git-cmd-wrapper
```

See more here: https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#local_directory

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. My question was related to golang "workspace", which works somewhat in my use case but not completely.

Comment: It works by accident of caching. You need to use `replace` in your go.mod. Look at the link I added to the top of the answer.

Comment: Adding "replace github.com/ldez/go-git-cmd-wrapper/v2 v2.6.0 => ../go-git-cmd-wrapper" to "go.mod" fixed the issue for me.